# OLE error C0000094

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ole

After calling to a com component procedure , an error raised

```
OLE error C0000094.
```

What does it mean, as searching yields [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q168354&GSSNB=1) from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697849/list-of-all-ole-error-codes).

which contain :

```
   0x80000001  -2147483647  Not implemented
   0x80000002  -2147483646  Ran out of memory
   0x80000003  -2147483645  One or more arguments are invalid
   0x80000004  -2147483644  No such interface supported
   0x80000005  -2147483643  Invalid pointer
   0x80000006  -2147483642  Invalid handle
   0x80000007  -2147483641  Operation aborted
   0x80000008  -2147483640  Unspecified error
   0x80000009  -2147483639  General access denied error
   0x8000000A  -2147483638  The data necessary to complete this operation
                            is not yet available.
   0x80004001  -2147467263  Not implemented
   0x80004002  -2147467262  No such interface supported
   0x80004003  -2147467261  Invalid pointer
   0x80004004  -2147467260  Operation aborted
   0x80004005  -2147467259  Unspecified error
   0x80004006  -2147467258  Thread local storage failure
   0x80004007  -2147467257  Get shared memory allocator failure
   0x80004008  -2147467256  Get memory allocator failure
   0x80004009  -2147467255  Unable to initialize class cache
   0x8000400A  -2147467254  Unable to initialize RPC services
   0x8000400B  -2147467253  Cannot set thread local storage channel control
   0x8000400C  -2147467252  Could not allocate thread local storage channel
                            control
   0x8000400D  -2147467251  The user supplied memory allocator is
                            unacceptable
   0x8000400E  -2147467250  The OLE service mutex already exists
   0x8000400F  -2147467249  The OLE service file mapping already exists
   0x80004010  -2147467248  Unable to map view of file for OLE service
   0x80004011  -2147467247  Failure attempting to launch OLE service
   0x80004012  -2147467246  There was an attempt to call CoInitialize a
                            second time while single threaded
   0x80004013  -2147467245  A Remote activation was necessary but was not
                            allowed
   0x80004014  -2147467244  A Remote activation was necessary but the
                            server name provided was invalid
   0x80004015  -2147467243  The class is configured to run as a security
                            id different from the caller
   0x80004016  -2147467242  Use of Ole1 services requiring DDE windows is
                            disabled
   0x80004017  -2147467241  A RunAs specification must be
                            <domain name>\<user name> or simply <user name>
   0x80004018  -2147467240  The server process could not be started.  The
                            pathname may be incorrect.
   0x80004019  -2147467239  The server process could not be started as the
                            configured identity.  The pathname may be
                            incorrect or unavailable.
   0x8000401A  -2147467238  The server process could not be started because
                            the configured identity is incorrect.  Check
                            the username and password.
   0x8000401B  -2147467237  The client is not allowed to launch this
                            server.
   0x8000401C  -2147467236  The service providing this server could not
                            be started.
   0x8000401D  -2147467235  This computer was unable to communicate with
                            the computer providing the server.
   0x8000401E  -2147467234  The server did not respond after being
                            launched.
   0x8000401F  -2147467233  The registration information for this server
                            is inconsistent or incomplete.
   0x80004020  -2147467232  The registration information for this interface
                            is inconsistent or incomplete.
   0x80004021  -2147467231  The operation attempted is not supported.
   0x8000FFFF  -2147418113  Catastrophic failure
   0x80070005  -2147024891  General access denied error
   0x80070006  -2147024890  Invalid handle
   0x8007000E  -2147024882  Ran out of memory
   0x80070057  -2147024809  One or more arguments are invalid


Debugging HRESULTS from OLE-DB
Some OLE-DB error messages, such as 80040e37 (Table 'x' does not exist) are
fairly obvious whether using ADO or OLE-DB. Others such as 0x80040E06 (Invalid chapter) are not as clear to an ADO developer. You can use the ITest/ISpy tools that ship with the OLE-DB SDK to spy on the OLE-DB calls. ITest/ISpy are similar to ODBC Spy and you can use them for complex debugging in ADO/DB applications.

This list was compiled from the Oledberr.h file, which ships with the OLE-DB SDK:

   Unsigned     Signed
     HRESULT   Hex HRESULT                    Description
   ----------  -----------  ----------------------------------------------
   0x80040E00  -2147217920  Invalid accessor
   0x80040E01  -2147217919  Creating another row would have exceeded the
                            total number of active rows supported by the
                            rowset
   0x80040E02  -2147217918  Unable to write with a read-only accessor
   0x80040E03  -2147217917  Given values violate the database schema
   0x80040E04  -2147217916  Invalid row handle
   0x80040E05  -2147217915  An object was open
   0x80040E06  -2147217914  Invalid chapter
   0x80040E07  -2147217913  A literal value in the command could not be                                   converted to the correct type due to a reason
                            other than data overflow
   0x80040E08  -2147217912  Invalid binding info
   0x80040E09  -2147217911  Permission denied
   0x80040E0A  -2147217910  Specified column does not contain bookmarks or
                            chapters
   0x80040E0B  -2147217909  Some cost limits were rejected
   0x80040E0C  -2147217908  No command has been set for the command object
   0x80040E0D  -2147217907  Unable to find a query plan within the given
                            cost limit
   0x80040E0E  -2147217906  Invalid bookmark
   0x80040E0F  -2147217905  Invalid lock mode
   0x80040E10  -2147217904  No value given for one or more required
                            parameters
   0x80040E11  -2147217903  Invalid column ID
   0x80040E12  -2147217902  Invalid ratio
   0x80040E13  -2147217901  Invalid value
   0x80040E14  -2147217900  The command contained one or more errors
   0x80040E15  -2147217899  The executing command cannot be canceled
   0x80040E16  -2147217898  The provider does not support the specified
                            dialect
   0x80040E17  -2147217897  A data source with the specified name already
                            exists
   0x80040E18  -2147217896  The rowset was builtover a live data feed and
                            cannot be restarted
   0x80040E19  -2147217895  No key matching the described characteristics
                            could be found within the current range
   0x80040E1A  -2147217894  Ownership of this tree has been given to the
                            provider
   0x80040E1B  -2147217893  The provider is unable to determine identity
                            for newly inserted rows
   0x80040E1C  -2147217892  No nonzero weights specified for any goals
                            supported, so goal was rejected; current goal
                            was not changed
   0x80040E1D  -2147217891  Requested conversion is not supported
   0x80040E1E  -2147217890  lRowsOffset would position you past either end
                            of the rowset, regardless of the cRows value
                            specified; cRowsObtained is 0
   0x80040E1F  -2147217889  Information was requested for a query, and the
                            query was not set
   0x80040E20  -2147217888  Provider called a method from IRowsetNotify in
                            the consumer and NT
   0x80040E21  -2147217887  Errors occurred
   0x80040E22  -2147217886  A non-NULL controlling IUnknown was specified
                            and the object being created does not support
                            aggregation
   0x80040E23  -2147217885  A given HROW referred to a hard- or soft-
                            deleted row
   0x80040E24  -2147217884  The rowset does not support fetching backwards
   0x80040E25  -2147217883  All HROWs must be released before new ones can
                            be obtained
   0x80040E26  -2147217882  One of the specified storage flags was not
                            supported
   0x80040E27  -2147217881  The comparison operator was invalid

   0x80040E28  -2147217880  The specified status flag was neither
                            DBCOLUMNSTATUS_OK nor DBCOLUMNSTATUS_ISNULL
   0x80040E29  -2147217879  The rowset cannot scroll backwards
   0x80040E2A  -2147217878  Invalid region handle
   0x80040E2B  -2147217877  The specified set of rows was not contiguous to
                            or overlapping the rows in the specified watch
                            region
   0x80040E2C  -2147217876  A transition from ALL* to MOVE* or EXTEND* was
                            specified
   0x80040E2D  -2147217875  The specified region is not a proper subregion
                            of the region identified by the given watch
                            region handle
   0x80040E2E  -2147217874  The provider does not support multi-statement
                            commands
   0x80040E2F  -2147217873  A specified value violated the integrity
                            constraints for a column or table
   0x80040E30  -2147217872  The given type name was unrecognized
   0x80040E31  -2147217871  Execution aborted because a resource limit has
                            been reached; no results have been returned
   0x80040E32  -2147217870  Cannot clone a command object whose command
                            tree contains a rowset or rowsets
   0x80040E33  -2147217869  Cannot represent the current tree as text
   0x80040E34  -2147217868  The specified index already exists
   0x80040E35  -2147217867  The specified index does not exist
   0x80040E36  -2147217866  The specified index was in use
   0x80040E37  -2147217865  The specified table does not exist
   0x80040E38  -2147217864  The rowset was using optimistic concurrency and
                            the value of a column has been changed since
                            it was last read
   0x80040E39  -2147217863  Errors were detected during the copy
   0x80040E3A  -2147217862  A specified precision was invalid
   0x80040E3B  -2147217861  A specified scale was invalid
   0x80040E3C  -2147217860  Invalid table ID
   0x80040E3D  -2147217859  A specified type was invalid
   0x80040E3E  -2147217858  A column ID was occurred more than once in the
                            specification
   0x80040E3F  -2147217857  The specified table already exists
   0x80040E40  -2147217856  The specified table was in use
   0x80040E41  -2147217855  The specified locale ID was not supported
   0x80040E42  -2147217854  The specified record number is invalid
   0x80040E43  -2147217853  Although the bookmark was validly formed, no
                            row could be found to match it
   0x80040E44  -2147217852  The value of a property was invalid
   0x80040E45  -2147217851  The rowset was not chaptered
   0x80040E46  -2147217850  Invalid accessor
   0x80040E47  -2147217849  Invalid storage flags
   0x80040E48  -2147217848  By-ref accessors are not supported by this
                            provider
   0x80040E49  -2147217847  Null accessors are not supported by this
                            provider
   0x80040E4A  -2147217846  The command was not prepared
   0x80040E4B  -2147217845  The specified accessor was not a parameter
                            accessor
   0x80040E4C  -2147217844  The given accessor was write-only
   0x80040E4D  -2147217843  Authentication failed
   0x80040E4E  -2147217842  The change was canceled during notification; no
                            columns are changed
   0x80040E4F  -2147217841  The rowset was single-chaptered and the chapter
                            was not released
   0x80040E50  -2147217840  Invalid source handle
   0x80040E51  -2147217839  The provider cannot derive parameter info and
                            SetParameterInfo has not been called
   0x80040E52  -2147217838  The data source object is already initialized
   0x80040E53  -2147217837  The provider does not support this method
   0x80040E54  -2147217836  The number of rows with pending changes has
                            exceeded the set limit
   0x80040E55  -2147217835  The specified column did not exist
   0x80040E56  -2147217834  There are pending changes on a row with a
                            reference count of zero
   0x80040E57  -2147217833  A literal value in the command overflowed the
                            range of the type of the associated column
   0x80040E58  -2147217832  The supplied HRESULT was invalid
   0x80040E59  -2147217831  The supplied LookupID was invalid
   0x80040E5A  -2147217830  The supplied DynamicErrorID was invalid
   0x80040E5B  -2147217829  Unable to get visible data for a newly-inserted
                            row that has not yet been updated
   0x80040E5C  -2147217828  Invalid conversion flag
   0x80040E5D  -2147217827  The given parameter name was unrecognized
   0x80040E5E  -2147217826  Multiple storage objects can not be open
                            simultaneously
   0x80040E5F  -2147217825  The requested filter could not be opened
   0x80040E60  -2147217824  The requested order could not be opened
   0x80040E61  -2147217823  Bad tuple
   0x80040E62  -2147217822  Bad coordinate
   0x80040E63  -2147217821  The given axis was not valid for this Dataset
   0x80040E64  -2147217820  One or more of the given cell ordinals was invalid
   0x80040E65  -2147217819  The supplied columnID was invalid
   0x80040E67  -2147217817  The supplied command does not have a DBID (Note:                             DBID is SQL shorthand for Database ID.)
   0x80040E68  -2147217816  The supplied DBID already exists
   0x80040E69  -2147217815  The maximum number of Sessions supported by the
                            provider has already been created. The consumer
                            must release one or more currently held Sessions
                            before obtaining a new Session object
   0x80040E72  -2147217806  The index ID is invalid
   0x80040E73  -2147217805  The initialization string does not conform
                            to specification
   0x80040E74  -2147217804  The OLE DB root enumerator did not return any
                            providers that matched an of the SOURCES_TYPEs
                            requested
   0x80040E75  -2147217803  The initialization string specifies a provider
                            which does not match the currently active
                            provider.
   0x80040E76  -2147217802  The specified DBID is invalid
   0x80040E6A  -2147217814  Invalid trustee value
   0x80040E6B  -2147217813  The trustee is not for the current data source
   0x80040E6C  -2147217812  The trustee does not support memberships/ 
                            collections
   0x80040E6D  -2147217811  The object is invalid or unknown to the provider
   0x80040E6E  -2147217810  No owner exists for the object
   0x80040E6F  -2147217809  The access entry list supplied is invalid
   0x80040E70  -2147217808  The trustee supplied as owner is invalid or
                            unknown to the provider
   0x80040E71  -2147217807  The permission supplied in the access entry list
                            is invalid
   0x80040E77  -2147217801  The ConstraintType was invalid or not supported
                            by the provider.
   0x80040E78  -2147217800  The ConstraintType was not CONSTRAINTTYPE_FOREIGNKEY
                            and cForeignKeyColumns was not zero

   0x80040E79  -2147217799  The Deferrability was invalid or the value was not
                            supported by the provider
   0x80040E80  -2147217792  The MatchType was invalid or the value was not
                            supported by the provider
   0x80040E8A  -2147217782  The UpdateRule or DeleteRule was invalid or the
                            value was not supported by the provider
   0x80040E8B  -2147217781  The pConstraintID did not exist in the data source
   0x80040E8C  -2147217780  The dwFlags was invalid
   0x80040E8D  -2147217779  The rguidColumnType pointed to a GUID that does not
                            match the object type of this column or this column
                            was not set
   0x80040E8E  -2147217778  The requested URL was out-of-scope
   0x80040E90  -2147217776  The provider could not drop the object
   0x80040E91  -2147217775  There is no source row
   0x80040E92  -2147217774  The OLE DB object represented by this URL is locked
                            by one or more other processes
   0x80040E93  -2147217773  The client requested an object type that is only
                            valid for a collection 
   0x80040E94  -2147217772  The caller requested write access to a read-only
                            object
   0x80040E95  -2147217771  The provider could not connect to the server for
                            this object
   0x80040E96  -2147217770  The provider could not connect to the server for
                            this object
   0x80040E97  -2147217769  The attempt to bind to the object timed out
   0x80040E98  -2147217768  The provider was unable to create an object at
                            this URL because an object named by this URL
                            already exists
   0x80040E99  -2147217767  The provider could not drop the object
   0x80040E9A  -2147217766  The provider was unable to create an object
                            at this URL because the server was out of
                            physical storage
   0x00040EC0       265920  Fetching requested number of rows would have
                            exceeded total number of active rows supported
                            by the rowset
   0x00040EC1       265921  One or more column types are incompatible;
                            conversion errors will occur during copying
   0x00040EC2       265922  Parameter type information has been overridden
                            by caller
   0x00040EC3       265923  Skipped bookmark for deleted or non-member row
   0x00040EC4       265924  Errors found in validating tree
   0x00040EC5       265925  There are no more rowsets
   0x00040EC6       265926  Reached start or end of rowset or chapter
   0x00040EC7       265927  The provider re-executed the command
   0x00040EC8       265928  Variable data buffer full
   0x00040EC9       265929  There are no more results
   0x00040ECA       265930  Server cannot release or downgrade a lock until
                            the end of the transaction
   0x00040ECB       265931  Specified weight was not supported or exceeded
                            the supported limit and was set to 0 or the
                            supported limit
   0x00040ECC       265932  Consumer is uninterested in receiving further
                            notification calls for this reason
   0x00040ECD       265933  Input dialect was ignored and text was returned
                            in different dialect
   0x00040ECE       265934  Consumer is uninterested in receiving further
                            notification calls for this phase
   0x00040ECF       265935  Consumer is uninterested in receiving further
                            notification calls for this reason
   0x00040ED0       265936  The operation is being processed asynchronously
   0x00040ED1       265937  In order to reposition to the start of the
                            rowset, the provider had to reexecute the
                            query; either the order of the columns changed
                            or columns were added to or removed from the
                            rowset
   0x00040ED2       265938  The method had some errors; errors have been
                            returned in the error array
   0x00040ED3       265939  Invalid row handle
   0x00040ED4       265940  A given HROW referred to a hard-deleted row


   0x00040ED5       265941  The provider was unable to keep track of all
                            the changes; the client must refetch the data
                            associated with the watch region using another
                            method
   0x00040ED6       265942  Execution stopped because a resource limit has
                            been reached; results obtained so far have been
                            returned but execution cannot be resumed
   0x00040ED7       265943  The bind failed because the provider was unable
                            to satisfy all of the bind flags or properties
   0x00040ED8       265944  A lock was upgraded from the value specified
   0x00040ED9       265945  One or more properties were changed as allowed
                            by provider
   0x00040EDA       265946  Errors occurred
   0x00040EDB       265947  A specified parameter was invalid
   0x00040EDC       265948  Updating this row caused more than one row to
                            be updated in the data source
   0x00040EDD       265949  The row has no row-specific columns
```

Comment: and the component is? what call raise the error?

Comment: The is a propriety of a third party. it was upon a function call with 3 params , 2 in one out. foo(interface1 in, interface2 out,integer in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be an Access Violation or a Division by zero exception.

But it is hard to know, since you provided no code at all.

Comment: Google goes into the "Division by zero exception" direction. An uncatched exception in the OLE implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

in windows.pas found:

```
  STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO   = DWORD($C0000094);
  STATUS_INTEGER_OVERFLOW         = DWORD($C0000095);
```